# va_arg gives something strange in cygwin x64

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

`asn1c` compiler has the following code (it's `C` code, **not** `C++`):

```
return asn1c_make_identifier(
                        AMI_MASK_ONLY_SPACES | AMI_NODELIMITER,
                        0, ((!stdname || (arg->flags & A1C_INCLUDES_QUOTED))
                                ? "\"" : "<"),
                        exprid ? exprid->Identifier : typename,
                        ((!stdname || (arg->flags & A1C_INCLUDES_QUOTED))
                                ? ".h\"" : ".h>"), 0);
```

For simplicity I could write the following (it doesn't affect the bug):

```
return asn1c_make_identifier(
                        AMI_MASK_ONLY_SPACES | AMI_NODELIMITER,
                        0, "str1",
                        "str2",
                        "str3", 0);
```

The function `asn1c_make_identifier` has the following definition `char * asn1c_make_identifier(enum ami_flags_e flags, asn1p_expr_t *expr, ...)` and standart `va_list` processing loop:

```
va_start(ap, expr);
while((str = va_arg(ap, char *)))
    size += 1 + strlen(str);
va_end(ap);
```

So, we get 3 strings and one zero. Everything seems to be good (and it works in Linux), but in cygwin I get the fourth iteration with non zero str. As a result segmentation fault happens. But if I write `(char*)` before `0` the code works as it should. Is it a real bug of cygwin or is it a bug in the source code? It's not my code and it contains a number of similiar zeros.

P.S. About `gcc` version

```
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.3
```

Comment: Are you aware that `0` is `int` and not `char*`?

Comment: @Deduplicator Well... I have thought about it, but why the programmer who wrote it, used this zero and in linux everthing worked and works now well?

Comment: @user2717575 probably due to [`__attribute__((sentinel))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html).

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: Nope, that's not for auto-correcting but for adding compiler-warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `0` is being interpreted as an integer, not as a pointer. Since the compiler cannot know what the types of variadic arguments are supposed to be, it can't convert to the type you intend.

So, when the compiler sees the expression `0` as an argument, it interprets it as an expression of type `int`, **not** of type `void *` (or `char *`, or any other pointer).

Because you're compiling for x64, `sizeof(int)` is 4 and `sizeof(char *)` is 8, so `va_arg` is reading more data from the stack than what's passed to it.

Instead, you should pass the constant `NULL`, which is of type `void *`, or for maximum portability, pass the expression `(char *)NULL`.

Comment: On Linux I also compiled it as x64 (I've checked the sizeof(char*) and it is 8)... I used Debian Wheezy and OpenSUSE 12.1 and 13.1

Answer (score 2):

Seems you got lucky on Linux, and the `int`-value `0`, maybe combined with surrounding junk, got interpreted as the sentinel `char*` `NULL` you should have provided.

Seems your luck ran out on cygwin, and a) it was a 64-bit system and b) the surrounding junk did not make a nullpointer together with the zero `int` you provided.

Welcome to the wonderful world of undefined behavior.

Just cast the sentinel to `char*` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a bug of the source code, since, as [Drew McGowen answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25390853/841108), the terminating `0` should in practice be a `NULL` *pointer* (not an `int`) - at least on Linux (since on x86-64 `int`-s and pointers have different sizes). To be picky, that should really be `(char*)0`.

You could however (assuming [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ....) :

1. declare the `asn1c_make_identifier` with [`__attribute__((sentinel))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html); it would warn you if you call it without a terminating `NULL`...
2. define a macro calling it with an *ending* `NULL`, e.g.

   ```
   #define asn1c_make_identifier(__VA_ARGS__) \
     asn1c_make_identifier(__VA__ARGS__,NULL)
   ```

So probably just changing a bit the header files should be enough. (Replace `NULL` with `(char*)0` if you want to be annoyingly and absolutely standard conforming).

I would also at your place suggest this improvement to the upstream authors of `asn1c`; perhaps a newer version has (or will) correct this bug.

Comment: `NULL` is not correct in general either; C allows it to be defined as a plain 0. POSIX does require `NULL` to be defined with `void *` type, but you should avoid using it and just be explicit with `(char *)0`.

Comment: @R.., do you mean that using plain zero (just 0, without casting to (char*) ) is correct here?

Comment: No. I mean using the macro `NULL` does not necessarily solve the problem (it's not a portable way to solve the problem). The correct solution is `(char *)0`.